# self-closing tags, "document types", and WYSIWYG HTML-Editor behavior

Tags: html

After using a `plaintext editor (Notepad++)` to create an HTML page with the basic structure like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
          <li> List Item 1 <br/> </li>
          <li> List Item 2 <br/> </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

I opened it in a `WYSIWYG HTML editor (BlueGriffon)` and noticed that the `<br/>` tags were automatically converted to `<br>` tags.

I was taught that `self-closing tags` were better practice and required for `XHTML`, and that `XHTML` was better than `HTML` because it was stricter.

So, I investigated further, and found these options in `BlueGriffon`:

[image]

However, regardless of which option I choose (`XHTML` or `HTML`), whenever I load the original `HTML` page, `BlueGriffon` converts the `<br/>` tags to `<br>`.

**My questions to y'all:**

1. Was I taught wrong that `self-closing tags` are better practice?
2. Why does this `WYSIWYG HTML editor (BlueGriffon)` not care to preserve `self-closing tags`? What's the philosophy here?

**Update**: turns out that if the document uses

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```

instead of

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

It does preserve the `self-closing tags`.

Answer (score 2):

> I was taught that self-closing tags were better practice

That's subjective.

> and required for XHTML

Yes

> and that XHTML was better than HTML because it was stricter.

It isn't. The rules, in prose, are more or less the same.

It could be argued that XHTML 1.0 is less strict that HTML 4.01 because XML DTDs are less expressive than SGML DTDs, but really that just means that traditional tools to automatically detect errors are less effective when working with XHTML.

Browsers deal in HTML anyway. Some have XML parsers which will trigger when presented with XHTML with the right Content-Type (almost nobody uses the right Content-Type).

Usually what that meant is that an error would slip into the document and trigger the Yellow Screen Of Death. These days I am given to understand most browsers that implement XML parsers that way now automatically fallback to an HTML parser if there's an error so the document still renders.

Using XHTML 1.x today means that you can't use any of the new features in HTML 5 and, while HTML 5 has an XML serialization, you can't use its Doctype with it so you are likely to end up in quirks rendering mode.

Also, since the web is made up almost entirely of HTML and not XHTML, guess which parser browser vendors invest more effort in optimising for speed?

> Why does this WYSIWYG HTML editor (BlueGriffon) not care to preserve self-closing tags? What's the philosophy here?

If it is converting XHTML to HTML when set to XHTML mode… that's a bug, not a philosophy.

… but the option you found is in the **New Document** window, and you opened an **existing** document you wrote with an HTML 5 Doctype.